# How can I identify what is the maximum frequency for iron core power inductors?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductor

I have a couple of yellow-white inductors like this: 
[image]

I can't find any datasheet and I don't know what is the maximum frequency where I can use these.

How can I measure it?

Comment: It should be noted that those are not inductors until you put a wire through or around them--what you have there are just ferrite cores (or iron cores, or whatever material those particular ones are).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in the US and unless they are knock-offs or Micrometals trademark expired recently, you can identify what material it is by the colors, yellow-white. That two tone paint scheme is Micrometals -26 material. Very common and excellent price/performance ratio. It's not high frequency nor very high flux (DC bias) but sits in the middle between which makes it a good choise for your average ~70 kHz output chokes in medium prices products.

> I can't find any datasheet

Here it is: http://www.micrometals.com/pcparts/pc_l.pdf and http://www.micrometals.com/material/index-26.html

> I don't know what is the maximum frequency

Looking at the datasheet, it starts to drop of at about 100 kHz. If your flux swing is low, you can go higher but there are better materials for very high frequencies.
[image: Extempt from datasheet]

> How can I measure it?

If you wind a few turns on it and have access to an LCR-meter, it will get you started for an unknown material. Critical parameters such as a loss curve is however quite time consuming to measure yourself but it is doable. The normal design procedure is to refer to the datasheet and make calculations from there.

Comment: Relying on paint colour is dangerous (too many core types, not enough colours).

Comment: it's actually a trademark (which doesn't expire if maintained), but it could be hard to enforce outside USA  I do not doubt that the composition of -26 is patented

Comment: Never said otherwise. But Micrometals do have a patent/trademark on that particular two-tone paint scheme which does correspond to -26 material.

Comment: Thank you ! This is that datasheet what I'm looking. I see the -26 material inductor from 100kHz to 1mHz decrease ~72 to ~58. Its maximum 20% decrease. I think this is acceptable. If I use 47uh it decreases 37uh. What do you think? Can I use it on 500kHz?

Comment: @Merpus You certainly can but there are other materials which perform better at 500 kHz. What is your DC bias and flux swing you plan on using @ 500 kHz?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what does it mean. I have a faulty ATX power supply, and in the power supply i found these rings. I would like to use with MP2307 DC-DC converter, 0-3A current. 20V input voltage, 12V output voltage.

Comment: If you intend you wind your own inductors, you must know or learn this. LI=NAB will set your peak flux without saturation. The other constrain is thermal limit. Will you be operating in CCM?

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'maximum frequency' which  is the self-resonant frequency, and
that depends on the windings on the core (and the effective capacitance of
those windings).   That, you cannot measure (because there are no windings).
There is a 'maximum frequency' set by the slow rate at which the applied
H field penetrates the core material, which determines whether the full
inductance (caused by magnetizing all the volume of the core) is available.
And, there is another 'maximum frequency' set by the losses, both
magnetization hysteresis and eddy-current induced in the (slightly
conductive) iron.  At any given drive level, exceeding that maximum
frequency will melt your wiring.

Because iron is a nonlinear material, the only way to get useful data
for power applications, is to experiment at high power drive.

Such cores as these may be used for filtering (where 'power loss' is a
good thing), or resonators (where 'power loss' is a bad thing), or
transformers (where 'power loss' depends on the output impedance
as much as on the core).   The core, as such, doesn't have any
hard maximum frequency of usability.

Comment: Thanks the answer. I would like to use in a DC-DC converter, frequency 300-500kHz. How can I notice the inductor not good to use?

Comment: I think winny's answer below is right. These are type 26. They are low frequency cores which i believe are good for 300-500k. if you want to switch slower than that you'll probably need the grey cores i think?

Comment: For a DC/DC converter with one transistor, of the 'blocking  oscillator' type, power load changes the frequency a LOT.   So, I presume your intent is to drive (PWM?) and use normal transformer coupling.   Most powdered-iron is intended for audio to low RF, and has energy limit  circa 0.15W/(gram-kHz) if one can scale from a textbook example.   _Transformer and Inductor Design Handbook_, by Wm. T. McLyman, is a useful guide.   A good transformer design is not simple.

Comment: I see the datasheet now what winny linked, thanks. On the page 3 there is not 'X' at -26 (yellow-white) in the line: DC Chokes: ≥50kHz or higher Et/N (Buck/Boost). What does it mean?

Comment: @Merpus It means that the AC flux losses are too high to be useful. Given enough turns and/or very low AC flux, you can still use it but the inductance versus loss will be bad and you are better of with high frequency ferrite.